# GSon serialization escaping my keys, why?

Tags: gson, android

I need to serialize my classes to this format to be sent to the server on a POST request:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "myId",
    "token": "myToken"
  }
}
```

but when I inspect the server's result the GSOn library keeps escaping the keys and the server fails since the JSON gets there malformed. Here's the response from the server:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>"{\"id\":\"myId\",\"token\":\"myToken\"}"}
```

And here is how I am serializing the code:

```
public class UserTest {
    @SerializedName("user")
    public UserDataTest user;
}

public class UserDataTest {

    UserDataTest(){};

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("token")
    public String token;
}
```

and I am testing it like this:

```
UserTest newUser = new UserTest();
UserDataTest tmp = new UserDataTest();
tmp.id = "myId";
tmp.token = "myToken";
newUser.user = tmp;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(newUser);
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("user", json);

// now I do a POST to the server
```

Can anyone spot the issue? thx!

Comment: Maybe the class must implement serializable?  public class UserTest implements Serializable{

Comment: no is not, the seralization is not correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the **POJO** classes and adapt it to this:

note that if the attribute of the objects have the same name as the json-key then you can omit the `@SerializedName("id")`, since this will be taken by **Gson** by default...

```
class UserDataTest {
    public String id;
    public String token;
    public UserDataTest(String id, String token) {
    this.id = id;
    this.token = token;
    }
}

class UserTest {
    public UserDataTest user;
    public UserTest(UserDataTest userDataTest) {
    this.user = userDataTest;
    }
}
```

## Test:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserTest newUser = new UserTest(new UserDataTest("myId", "myToken"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(newUser);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```